# Hover Scroll Div Parallax

Tags: html, scroll, hover, slide, parallax

I am trying to recreate the home page of this site... http://spooz-creation.com/

I want to slide a large div (green) that contains other divs (yellow) left and right in the users window (blue). Upon loading, the content div (green) will be centered in the users window like the example site. There will also be a static header (pink) with nav elements.

I really want the scroll to be hover activated like the example site. Also I would like the content giv (green) height to be flexible based off users window height.

Adding the parallax effect on top of all that would be epic but not totally needed if to complicated.

!!!!! (WIREFRAME EXAMPLE) !!!!!!
http://lpaoriginal.files.wordpress.com/2012/07/desktop.jpg

Please help! I've been trying for days to figure this out!

Answer (score 0):

This JQuery plug-in might just do exactly what you're looking for.

[JParallax](http://stephband.info/jparallax/)

Been using it for a project I'm currently working on. Great thing about it is you can limit the plug-in to x-axis only or y-axis only.